# Rails 2: joint multi table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

Sorry, i'am newbie

I have database:

### Migrate

-Mst_group tble

```
class CreateMstGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :mst_groups do |t|
      t.string :group_name
    end
  end
end
```

-Mst_japan

```
class CreateMstJapans < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :mst_japans do |t|
      t.string :name_level
    end
  end
end
```

-Tbl_user

```
class CreateTblUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :tbl_users do |t|
      t.string :login_name, :null =>false,:limit =>15
      t.string :password,:null =>false,:limit =>50
      t.string :full_name,:null =>false
      t.string :full_name_kana
      t.string :email,:null =>false
      t.string :tel,:null =>false,:limit =>15
      t.date :birthday,:null =>false  

      t.references :mst_groups
    end
  end
end
```

-Tbl_detail_user_japan

```
class CreateTblDetailUserJapans < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :tbl_detail_user_japans do |t|
      t.date :start_date
      t.date :end_date
      t.integer :total

      t.references :tbl_users
      t.references :mst_japans
    end
  end
end
```

### Model

```
class MstGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tbl_users
end

class MstJapan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tbl_detail_user_japans
end

class TblUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mst_group
  has_one :tbl_detail_user_japan
end

class TblDetailUserJapan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tbl_user
  belongs_to :mst_japan
end
```

### Controller

```
def index
  @user= ???????
end
```

How to write command select  : **login_name, full_name, full_name_kana, email, tel, group_name, name_lever, start_date, end_date, total** in  controller

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to retrieve the User object. You need to tell Rails how to find the TblUser object. If, for example, the user ID is known, let's say in a variable called 'id' then you would do:

```
def index
  @user=TblUser.find(id)
end
```

It depends on your application logic how Rails would know which user you need. You may need an input from the user in case of log in, etc.
(Typically in Rails you would call the table 'Users', by convention tables and classes have the same name and then you wouldn't need to call the class TblUser)

That is all you need in the controller, you don't need to tell it which fields you  want. 
Then in the View you can access all the fields:
Fields on TblUser, example:

```
<%= @user.email %>
```

You can access the fields from related objects through the relations, example:

```
<%= @user.mst_group.group_name %>
```

Hope that helps to get you started.